# IE7 not loading javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

There is plenty of information on the internet regarding this problem, however I cannot find something quite specific to this.

I have been updating websites with new eu cookie law information (javascript). I have just noticed somewhere along the line ie7 is not loading the javascript files. Tested with an alert and it does not show.

Script include:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="cookiesJs/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="cookiesJs/c.js"></script>
```

c.js:

```
document.write('<style type="text/css">a{text-decoration: none;}#cookieMessage {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #222;background-color: #D1D3D4;padding: 8px;height: auto;position: fixed;width:200px;margin: 0px 0px 0 0;bottom:0px;right:10px;border:#FFF 2px solid;border-bottom:0px;padding: 0px 8px 8px 8px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;border-top-right-radius: 8px;border-top-left-radius: 8px;text-align:left;overflow:hidden;z-index:999999;}#cookieMessage h6 {font-size: 14px;text-transform: uppercase;padding: 0px;margin-top: 8px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-left: 0px;color: #222;}#cookieMessage img {border:0px;}#cookieMessage p {text-align: left;font-size: 11px;padding: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;margin-left: 0px;color: #222;}#cookieMessage p a {color: #333;}#cookieMessage h6 a {color: #333;text-decoration: none;}#arrow{margin-top: -20px;}</style>');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#polup").toggle(function(){
        $("#cookieMessage").animate({height:120},500);
        $("#arrow").animate({height:0},160);
    },function(){
        $("#cookieMessage").animate({height:22},500);
        $("#arrow").animate({height:14},160);
    });
});

var accepted = get_cookie("accepted");
if(accepted == null){
    document.cookie = "accepted=no; path=/"; // initialize the cookie
}

function accept(){
    // when the client clicks accept
    $("#cookieMessage").fadeOut();
    $.cookie("accepted", "yes", {
       expires : 360,           //expires in 10 days
       path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
    });
}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
// method to retrieve a cookie based upon its name entered
    {
      var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );

      if ( results )
        return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
      else
        return null;
    }
var x = get_cookie("consentCookie");
    if(x == null){
        document.cookie = "consentCookie=yes; path=/";
        location.reload();
    }var x = get_cookie("consentCookie");
        if((x == "yes") && (accepted == "no")){

        //if the cookie does not exist it is the users first time on the page
        document.cookie = "consentCookie=no; path=/";
        var policy = '<div id="cookieMessage"><h6>Cookie Policy</h6><p>Our website uses cookies. By using our website and agreeing to this policy, you consent to our use of cookies.<a href="cookie_policy.htm">Find out more about cookies.</a></p><p><a href="#" onclick="accept();"><img src="cookiesJs/cookieimg/cookie.gif" width="20" height="20" alt="cookie" style="margin-bottom:-5px;" /> I accept</a></p></div>';
        document.write(policy);
    }else if((x == "no") && (accepted == "no")){
        // if they have visited before but not accepted
        document.write('<div id="cookieMessage">');
        var policy = '<a href="#_" id="polup"><h6>Cookie Policy</h6> <img id="arrow" align="right" src="cookiesJs/cookieimg/arrow.gif" width="18" height="14" alt="arrow" /></a></h6>';
        document.write(policy);
        document.write('<p>Our website uses cookies. By using our website and agreeing to this policy, you consent to our use of cookies.</p><p><a href="cookie_policy.htm">Find out more about cookies.</a></p><p><a href="#" onclick="accept();"><img src="cookiesJs/cookieimg/cookie.gif" width="20" height="20" alt="cookie" style="margin-bottom:-5px;" /> I accept</a></p></div>');
        $("#cookieMessage").css("height","20");
    }else{
        //if they  have visited and accepted
        document.write('<div id="cookieMessage" style="display: none"><h6>Cookie Policy</h6></div>');
    }
```

I cannot understand why IE is not loading the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [trailing comma](http://trailingcomma.com/)

```
       path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie
```

Remove the trailing comma and magic should hopefully happen and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a compilation problem:

You've got one line that says this:

```
}var x = get_cookie("consentCookie");
```

Looks like a copy/paste issue.

I find that sometimes IE7 will refuse point blank if there's an error, whereas other browsers will "do their best" and load/execute what they can.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however IE is still not loading it after I fixed that